# Syntax error when parsing JSON string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I have a sample JSON with some part of my webpage rendered :

```
{"html": {"#data": "\n<h2>Data</h2>\n<div class="\&quot;manufacturer-image\&quot;">\n \n</div>\n
<form action="\&quot;/manage/update-manufacturer-data/3\&quot;" method="\&quot;post\&quot;">\n \n 
<div class="\&quot;field\&quot;">\n <div class="\&quot;label\&quot;">\n <label for="\&quot;id_name\&quot;">Nazwa</label>:\n 
</div>\n \n \n <div class="\&quot;error\&quot;">\n 
<input id="\&quot;id_name\&quot;" name="\&quot;name\&quot;" maxlength="50" type="\&quot;text\&quot;">\n 
<ul class="\&quot;errorlist\&quot;"><li>Pole wymagane</li></ul>\n </div>\n \n </div>\n\n 
<div class="\&quot;field\&quot;">\n <div class="\&quot;label\&quot;">\n <label for="\&quot;id_image\&quot;">Zdjecie</label>:\n 
</div>\n \n \n <div>\n <input name="\&quot;image\&quot;" id="\&quot;id_image\&quot;" type="\&quot;file\&quot;">\n 
</div>\n \n </div>\n\n <div class="\&quot;field\&quot;">\n <div class="\&quot;label\&quot;">\n 
<label for="\&quot;id_description\&quot;">Opis</label>:\n </div>\n \n \n <div>\n 
<textarea id="\&quot;id_description\&quot;" rows="10" cols="40" name="\&quot;description\&quot;"></textarea>\n </div>\n \n 
</div>\n \n <div class="\&quot;buttons\&quot;">\n <input class="\&quot;ajax-save-button" button\"="" type="\&quot;submit\&quot;">\n 
</div>\n</form>"}}
```

This string is returned with ajax call and jQuery 1.6.1 throws an error :

`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object`

in the following part of the code :

```
parseJSON: function( data ) {
    if ( typeof data !== "string" || !data ) {
        return null;
    }
    // Make sure leading/trailing whitespace is removed (IE can't handle it)
    data = jQuery.trim( data );

    // Attempt to parse using the native JSON parser first
    if ( window.JSON && window.JSON.parse ) {
        console.warn('data: ', data);
        var ret;
        try{
            ret = window.JSON.parse(data);
        } catch(e){
            ret = {};
            console.warn(e);
        }
        return ret;
        //return window.JSON.parse( data );
    }
```

What am I missing here ?

---

EDIT:

I have parsed through the previous 'json' (which by the way was created with python's simplejson lib, so I wonder how can this be working anywhere) and now jsonlint shows, that I have proper JSON. Still the problem remains the same. The new string :

```
{"html": [{"#data": "\n<h2>Data</h2>\n<div class=&quot;manufacturer-image&quot;>\n    \n</div>\n<form action=&quot;/manage/update-manufacturer-data/4&quot; method=&quot;post&quot;>\n        \n    <div class=&quot;field&quot;>\n        <div class=&quot;label&quot;>\n            <label for=&quot;id_name&quot;>Nazwa</label>:\n        </div>\n        \n        \n            <div class=&quot;error&quot;>\n                <input id=&quot;id_name&quot; type=&quot;text&quot; name=&quot;name&quot; maxlength=&quot;50&quot; />\n                <ul class=&quot;errorlist&quot;><li>Pole wymagane</li></ul>\n            </div>\n        \n    </div>\n\n    <div class=&quot;field&quot;>\n        <div class=&quot;label&quot;>\n            <label for=&quot;id_image&quot;>Zdjecie</label>:\n        </div>\n        \n        \n            <div>\n                <input type=&quot;file&quot; name=&quot;image&quot; id=&quot;id_image&quot; />\n            </div>\n        \n    </div>\n\n    <div class=&quot;field&quot;>\n        <div class=&quot;label&quot;>\n            <label for=&quot;id_description&quot;>Opis</label>:\n        </div>\n        \n        \n            <div>\n                <textarea id=&quot;id_description&quot; rows=&quot;10&quot; cols=&quot;40&quot; name=&quot;description&quot;></textarea>\n            </div>\n        \n    </div>\n  \n    <div class=&quot;buttons&quot;>\n        <input type=&quot;submit&quot; class=&quot;ajax-save-button button&quot; />\n    </div>\n</form>"}]}
```

EDIT2:
Ok it looks, that JSOn leaving my backend is proper but dumb jQuery adds additional quotes around each '"' which is kinda odd.

Comment: i dont know but from the look of it the json seems to be invalid...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The data is [not](http://ideone.com/kjAZ0) valid JSON, since `\"` in strings seems to have been replaced with `"\`.

Contact the author of that supposedly-JSON and notify him or her that there are [plenty](http://php.net/json) [of](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) [JSON](http://json.org/) [libraries](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) [available](http://json.codeplex.com/) [for](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) [all](http://flori.github.com/json/) [languages](http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/json) [and](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) [platforms](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

Comment: You can always use: http://jsonlint.com/ to check if it's valid JSON. Also, the above is not valid JSON.

Comment: @JamieRRytlewski Good point. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to generate a link to a specific validation, so I used the JavaScript mode at ideone.

Answer (score 10):

```
storejson= getJSonObject("@ViewBag.JsonData");

function getJSonObject(value) {
    return $.parseJSON(value.replace(/&quot;/ig, '"'));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I might be mistaken here but I think it's due to the JSON data itself it doesn't work.
The JSON parser probably chokes on the double-quotes in the HTML contained in the JSON'ed string variable. I think it will work when you pre-process the HTML string before outputting the JSON data so you change the double-quotes into something else. ( and do the other way around after parsing the JSON data )

An example might clarify a bit:

instead of this:
`{"html": { "#data": "<input name="somename" type="text"/>"} }`

i'd try to use this:

`{"html": { "#data": "<input name=&quot;somename&quot; type=&quot;text&quot;/>"} }`

Hope it helps...

Comment: this worked for me. to simplify the quotation replacement I used `JSON.stringify(foo).replace(/\\"/g, '\\\\"')`

Answer (score 2):

JSON = Javascript Object Notation, therefor the value of the `"#data"`property is an invalid string.

You can validate your JSON [here](http://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score -1):

I think it's probably the fact that you are using the same double quotes in your HTML code itself so the JSON thinks its a property value, try using single quotes for all the HTML

Comment: This is not reasonnable!